# NSXML Parser select Keys and write in different Labels

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing, xcode5

Ιn my iOS app, I parse data from an XML file. The data looks like this in the Log:

How can I now the single Keys "result, identifier, etc." read and continue to use from the index 2. Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: can you provide the data?

Comment: hello,

after parsing my MutableArray looks like this. How can I read the keys with their values ​​and fill in a table view.

2014-02-22 09:33:19.194 Info[622:70b] Eintrag an Index 2: { "13.06.14" = Spieltag2; 2 = Identifier; "3 : 2" = Ergebniss; "Brasilien : Kroatien" = Spielpaarung;

Thanks.